# how to using mongoose method to get value of a inside referenced object in Node js web app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var jobs = new mongoose.Schema({
    jobNumber: Number,
    jobField: String,
    jobTitle: String,
    jobCity: String,
    jobArea: String,
    jobAddress: String,
    jobPhone: String,
    jobInsurance: String,
    jobSalary: Number,
    jobAccommodation: String,
    jobDescription: String,
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    },

    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

//EXPORT
module.exports = mongoose.model("jobs", jobs);


//SHOW OWNED JOBS
router.get("/myjobs", function (req, res) {

    jobs.find({},function (err, myjobs) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {

            res.render("filteredJobs", {
                datas: myjobs
            });

        }
    });
});
```

In this case I will get all the data but, how can I find by username or author._id?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
router.get("/myjobs/:user", function (req, res) { 
   jobs.find({'author.username':user},function (err, myjobs) {
     ...
   }
}
```